# How to obtain the short domain name from the User principal name (UPN)

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, directoryservices

I am trying to obtain the short domain name from the user principal name (UPN).
Basically I have a user:
blakegriffin@Artboard.onmicrosoft.com

I know windows maps this to the short domain name of: Artboard\blakegriffin

Is there a Windows API function that I can call whereby I supply the UPN (blakegriffin@Artboard.onmicrosoft.co) and retrieve the short domain name(Artboard\blakegriffin) ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly , you want to get the **Down-Level Logon Name** from the UPN with some tools like API,right?

**On Azure AD**,there is no Attributes of NetBIOS Name in Azure AD.So you cannot reach that.

**On local AD**,as I known, there is no such way to obtain Down-level logon Name directly from User Principle Name.

The down-level logon name format is used to specify a domain and a user account in that domain, for example, DOMAIN\UserName. This DOMAIN is a **NetBIOS domain name**.

User principal name (UPN) format is used to specify an Internet-style name, such as UserName@Example.Microsoft.com. This UPN suffix. Also known as the domain name.

So, you need to know that whether the NetBIOS domain name is compatible with the UPN suffix.Then you can confirm your  Down-Level Logon Name.

See more details about User Name Formats in [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380525(v=vs.85).aspx).

---

If you just want to obtain **SAM Account** after joining Azure AD DS, there is a way to get the SAM Account using Email address **on local AD**. See more details about how to get SAM account from Email Address, in [this post](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/simple-ad-script-to-get-sam-account-ids-from-email-address/).

There isn't a way to get this **on Azure AD** either.

Comment: It's a bit strange since if I am logged into my account and do a
"whoami /upn" I get:

blakegriffin@Artboard.onmicrosoft.com
while if I do a whoami/user the username that pops up is:

"ArtBoard\blakegriffin"
I would think there is still some API I can call to get this conversion for another user.

Comment: @blake_griffin  Well, if you find the API , please post here and tell me. Thanks.;)

Answer (score 0):

Found this API call:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725484(v=vs.85).aspx
[image]

It's resolved the issue.

Comment: Cheers! it's excellent to find this. I'm glad to learn about this.